# Stroke image in SKSpriteNode with path (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

If I have an image SKSpriteNode in swift, is there a way I can draw a path around the non transparent parts of the image node with a colour, so the edges are sharper.

For example, if I have a weird shape image and put that in my scene as an SKSpriteNode with a transparent background, can I somehow draw around that shape with a path to make the edges look sharper?

Thanks